# Two tabular aligned on top of each other

Tags: tables, align

I want to have two tabular centered but the bottom one to be aligned with top one

[image: to be in the middle]

I don't want it to look like that

[image]

still the  top should be centered and the bottom aligned

```
\begin{table}[!h]
\begin{center}
\caption{Survey Table}
\label{table4}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Ref. &     D2D      &     BS        & Interference &   QoS  \\
     & Interference & Interference  &   avoidance  &        \\
     &   reduction  &   reduction   &              &        \\
\hline
\cite{2}
& $\boxtimes$ 
& $\text{\rlap{$\checkmark$}}\square$ 
& $\boxtimes$ 
& $\boxtimes$ \\
 \hline
\cite{3}
& $\text{\rlap{$\checkmark$}}\square$
& $\text{\rlap{$\checkmark$}}\square$
& $\boxtimes$
& $\text{\rlap{$\checkmark$}}\square$ \\
\hline
\cite{5}
& $\text{\rlap{$\checkmark$}}\square$
& $\text{\rlap{$\checkmark$}}\square$
& $\boxtimes$
& $\text{\rlap{$\checkmark$}}\square$ \\
\hline
\cite{6}
&
&
& $\text{\rlap{$\checkmark$}}\square$
& $\text{\rlap{$\checkmark$}}\square$ \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\\
\\


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Ref. &   Self         &  Less     &   Controlled \\
     & organized     &  Spatial   &       by     \\
     &               & diversity  &              \\
\hline
\cite{2}
& $\text{\rlap{$\checkmark$}}\square$ 
& $\text{\rlap{$\checkmark$}}\square$ 
& D2D  \\
\hline
\cite{3}
& $\boxtimes$ 
& $\text{\rlap{$\checkmark$}}\square$ 
& D2D $\&$ BS \\
\hline
\cite{5}
& $\boxtimes$ 
& $\text{\rlap{$\checkmark$}}\square$ 
& BS \\
\hline
\cite{6}
& $\boxtimes$ & $\boxtimes$ 
& BS \\
\hline

\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, I just stack the two `tabular`s with left alignment and zero gap.  Note that I redefined `\cite`, since the OP did not provide citation data.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,stackengine}
\def\cite#1{#1}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!h]
\begin{center}
\caption{Survey Table}
\label{table4}
\stackengine{0pt}{%
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Ref. &     D2D      &     BS        & Interference &   QoS  \\
     & Interference & Interference  &   avoidance  &        \\
     &   reduction  &   reduction   &              &        \\
\hline
\cite{2}
& $\boxtimes$ 
& $\text{\rlap{$\checkmark$}}\square$ 
& $\boxtimes$ 
& $\boxtimes$ \\
 \hline
\cite{3}
& $\text{\rlap{$\checkmark$}}\square$
& $\text{\rlap{$\checkmark$}}\square$
& $\boxtimes$
& $\text{\rlap{$\checkmark$}}\square$ \\
\hline
\cite{5}
& $\text{\rlap{$\checkmark$}}\square$
& $\text{\rlap{$\checkmark$}}\square$
& $\boxtimes$
& $\text{\rlap{$\checkmark$}}\square$ \\
\hline
\cite{6}
&
&
& $\text{\rlap{$\checkmark$}}\square$
& $\text{\rlap{$\checkmark$}}\square$ \\
\hline
\end{tabular}%
}{%
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Ref. &   Self         &  Less     &   Controlled \\
     & organized     &  Spatial   &       by     \\
     &               & diversity  &              \\
\hline
\cite{2}
& $\text{\rlap{$\checkmark$}}\square$ 
& $\text{\rlap{$\checkmark$}}\square$ 
& D2D  \\
\hline
\cite{3}
& $\boxtimes$ 
& $\text{\rlap{$\checkmark$}}\square$ 
& D2D $\&$ BS \\
\hline
\cite{5}
& $\boxtimes$ 
& $\text{\rlap{$\checkmark$}}\square$ 
& BS \\
\hline
\cite{6}
& $\boxtimes$ & $\boxtimes$ 
& BS \\
\hline
\end{tabular}%
}{U}{l}{F}{F}{S}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could use `\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}...\end{tabular}` around the two tables, but this would make somewhat difficult to paste them.

With `varwidth` we can do it, setting `\lineskip` to the negative of the rule thickness.

Note that I defined two personal commands for the boxes: do this every time you use some particular construction more than in a couple of places. The typescript will be clearer and you'll be able to change the definitions whenever you want without chasing through the document.

Note also that `center` shouldn't be used in a `table` environment: prefer the `\centering` declaration.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,varwidth,caption}

\newcommand{\Crossed}{$\boxtimes$}
\newcommand{\Checked}{\makebox[0pt][l]{$\checkmark$}$\square$}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\caption{Survey Table}
\label{table4}

\begin{varwidth}{\columnwidth}
\setlength{\lineskip}{-0.4pt}\raggedright
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Ref. &     D2D      &     BS        & Interference &   QoS  \\
     & Interference & Interference  &   avoidance  &        \\
     &   reduction  &   reduction   &              &        \\
\hline
\cite{2}
& \Crossed 
& \Checked 
& \Crossed 
& \Crossed \\
 \hline
\cite{3}
& \Checked
& \Checked
& \Crossed
& \Checked \\
\hline
\cite{5}
& \Checked
& \Checked
& \Crossed
& \Checked \\
\hline
\cite{6}
&
&
& \Checked
& \Checked \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Ref. &   Self         &  Less     &   Controlled \\
     & organized     &  Spatial   &       by     \\
     &               & diversity  &              \\
\hline
\cite{2}
& \Checked 
& \Checked 
& D2D  \\
\hline
\cite{3}
& \Crossed 
& \Checked 
& D2D $\&$ BS \\
\hline
\cite{5}
& \Crossed 
& \Checked 
& BS \\
\hline
\cite{6}
& \Crossed & \Crossed 
& BS \\
\hline

\end{tabular}
\end{varwidth}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]