# Centering left justified

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I would like to combine left justification and centering for a figure with multiple panels created using sidesubfloat.  I.e. the entire block should be centered on the page, but with the left side of the graphics aligned.  Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you're looking for? Sounds like you could either use the `float` package or the `center` environment.

Comment: Place all of them in a `minipage` with the width of the widest element, and put that centered in the `figure`-environment. But to be honest, i don't know `sidesubfloat` so i cannot be sure. That is why minimal working examples are helpful.

Comment: Features of the `stackengine` package can also be used, depending on your requirements.  For example, this answer centers a left-aligned stack of `tabular`s. Image panels would be done in the same way: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/253326/two-tabular-aligned-on-top-of-each-other/253329#253329.